# How to export IntelliJ theme?

Tags: intellij-idea

When i modified my color scheme, `IntelliJ` asked me to save it as a new one. Is is possible for me to export this theme on one computer in order to reimport to a different one?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`File` | `Export Settings` (enable just the **Color Schemes** or the set of options that you need to export). On another machine use `File` | `Import Settings`.

See also the [help section](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-and-importing-settings.html).

Comment: This exports all installed color schemes. Is there a way to export only the current one or any single one?

Comment: Note that in recent versions (currently looking at 2021.2.1) the option is under `File` | `Manage IDE Settings` | `Export Settings`.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a way to only export the color scheme:

Go to `File` | `Settings` on Windows or `IntelliJ IDEA` | `Preferences` on Mac. Then, go to `Editor`→`Color Scheme`, click the icon that looks like a cog/gear, and click Export.

Comment: This only exports the editor color scheme, not the combination of overall theme + editor color scheme. Need a way to create a new theme so I can switch to it without going into settings to change both of them every time.

Comment: @Ryan Have you looked into this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/user-interface-themes.html