# How to save custom editor theme in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

A long time I used `default` theme on **Android Studio**, but now I try change this theme to `Darcula`. I make some fixes in this theme (and save this `Save as>ThemeName`)

[image]

How I can save this theme for using on another Android Studio (at home for ex.) ?

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14058932/244611